# HTTP Post Request in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, http, post, http-post

I've been trying to make an Http post request from visual basic but every time I get an exception, there is nothing wrong with authentication or headers since the same code works in C#, what am I missing to do in VB.Net to make it work?

here is what I've tried:
[vb]

```
    Sub test()
    Dim URL As String = "https://myurl.com.do"
    Dim User As String = "user"
    Dim Key As String = "key"
    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    client.BaseAddress = New Uri(URL)
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Auth1", User)
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Auth2", Key)
    client.Timeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 160)

    Dim values = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
    {"param1", "1.00"},
    {"param2", "0"},
    {"param3", "1.00"},
    {"param4", "349000000"}
    }

    Dim content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(values)


    Try
        Dim response = client.PostAsync(URL, content).Result

        If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then

            Try
                Dim OB As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("error")
            End Try
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", CInt(response.StatusCode), response.ReasonPhrase)
        End If

        Console.ReadKey()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

and this is the exception I'm getting:
 (exception on first try catch,on the Dim response line ):

[image: exception on first try catch]

[image: Inner exeption]

this is my working C# code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string URL = "https://myurl.com.do";         

        String User = "user";
        String Key = "key";

        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        values.Add("param1", "1.00");
        values.Add("param2", "0");
        values.Add("param3", "1.00");
        values.Add("param4", "349000000");


        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 160);          
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")  );

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Auth1", User);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Auth2", Key);                    

        try
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(URL, content).Result; 
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                   
                try
                {
                    string b = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    Dictionary<string, string> dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);// response.Content.read
                    object OB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);// response.Content.read               
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {


                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error de conexion");
        }
    }
```

what am I missing or doing wrong in vb.net?

Comment: I can't see images. Can you put the text of the exception?

Comment: Is there a reason for not typing 'response'?  Do you have Option Infer On?  You're also dropping explicit typing on other variables - these are 'Object' if you don't have Option Infer On.

Comment: Thank you all guys! just digging into the inner exeptions found the real issue, the answer is in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453353/http-post-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy pasted answer from this next link:

[Http post error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453353/http-post-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

I think its because you are connecting to "https" url. In this case you have to add following line to your code.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

It will accept "ssl" protocol for your request. `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` handler just controls certificate validity.